# I need to find out of point on line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

[image: Illustration]

I need to find out the coordinates of red point at the line. All known values i drew at the picture. Also i have distance for the point 0.2

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class raycast : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up);
        if (hit.collider != null) 
        {
            float angle = 360 - Mathf.Abs(transform.eulerAngles.z);
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point);
            float totalRot = 270 - (90 + angle);
            print(hit.point);
        }
    }
}
```

I need the coords for DrawLine cus he needs vector3 to draw line. This is for throwing things with reflection

Comment: It is not possible to find red point because it might be in any position at the ray. Perhaps you really want something else...

Comment: I don't quite understand the relationship between the image and your code ... like what value refers to what in your image? What is the actual underlying thing you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MBo I need not only this red point. It can be any point on the line, I just need point at the kine to draw line

Comment: @derHugo script is for draw lines in unity. Image for illustrating my idea. If I showed this in unity you maybe could understand what I need

Comment: Well. If you knew how far away the dot was you could work it out. Given that the angles are known and while its been about 40 years my brain says you could find a direction and multiply it by a distance and then add it to the start. But that diagrams is chaos

Comment: Reflected ray has parametric equation P0 + t * d, where P0 is point (2, 1.15) and d is direction vector (cos(150), sin(150)), roughly (-0.866, 0.5). But I think you'll need more general case.

Comment: Unity has `Vector3.Reflect` .. you barely know to know any underlying math yourself... but still we don't really understand what that point shall be and how your diagram relates to the code you have currently ..

Comment: @derHugo if u need so i delete this code, i just wanna know how to find out this point. Im in 9 grade

Comment: also i need this to Ray, for like throwing grenade. And Vector3.Reflect its not i want

Comment: @Smile3329 I wrote ray description. Is it unclear?

Comment: Sorry but various people now have already told you that we don't have enough information to fully understand what exactly you are after ... the point can not be found without knowing how far away from the reflection point it shall be or how exactly you want those angles to behave etc ... As said before: what is your actual use case? What are you trying to achieve by that? Maybe there is a way easier way to get it .. see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: and tbh Vector2.Reflect would pretty much be what you are looking for instead of all that angle and Euler calculations you are using currently...

Comment: @derHugo i added missing info, also why do i need

Comment: OK, so substitute distance 0.2 instead of t in my formula or instead of d in Chuck's one.

Comment: Vector2/3.Reflect and formulas didnt work. At the formulas ray just reflecting around "circle", and at the Vector.Reflect it reflecting at 90 degrees or down

Comment: Consider a polar to Cartesian coordinate transformation.

Answer (score -1):

Paint has a text tool; your handwriting is so bad I can't read it. You seem to have it all worked out, though, so it's not clear what you're asking for. Only issue I think I see is that the orange angles are almost certainly wrong. It looks like "90 + su", and I don't know what that means. Maybe 90 + 30? 90+30 makes sense if it's drawn to the -y axis, but you have it between the two gray lines.

But anyways, it's just your intermediate point (2, 1.15) plus the offset from the new ray. You need to decide some distance d along that line, and an angle to horizontal like (I think) 30 degrees. The red dot's x position is (2 - d*cosd(30)) and the y position is (1.15 + d*sind(30)). I use sind and cosd as the version of sine and cosine that take degrees arguments; if you're using regular sine and cosine then be sure to convert the angle to radians. Resulting point would be relative to your (0,0) origin.

This is just appropriate for the angle that I think you've got drawn here, which is to the lower-left of the upper line (to the negative x axis), but the lower gray line is taking angles from a different datum (positive y axis). If you're going to code something robust (read: reliable) then you'll need to start taking measurements from the same datum every single time.

Comment: no it didnt worked its reflecting around "circle"

Comment: @Smile3329 no idea what you mean when you say it's getting reflected around "circle". You don't have a circle marked in your diagram and you're not saying if it's reflected horizontally or vertically. If you've got screenshots of what you're seeing that'd be a huge help.